# Issue in list view web part in Sharepoint Publishing page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, publishing-site, publishing-page, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have a the publishing Site "http://devsp11/sites/publishingSite".
Now on home page i want to provision list view web part with "Add new Item Link" of Documents library.

I have probisioned list view web part as below.Where i have inline with red is my list view web part adnd it's propert full toolbar.
But still i am not getting "Add new item Link" in list view web part.
Can anyone please help me out to find a root cause of this issue ?

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code to provision list view webpart ?

Comment: @GautamSheth I have tried in both the way. First i have provisioned list view web part by code. but i found issue so i have provisioned list view web part Out of the box. But still issue existed in both the way

Comment: So you just edited the page and added the webpart and still its not showing the upload link ?

Comment: @GautamSheth I have created new publishing site . Created new Publishing Page . Added new list view web part OOTB of Document library on Header zone. but still it's not showing "Add new item Link".

Comment: Can you click on Settings (gear icon on the top right)  > Show ribbon and check ?

Comment: Also another thing, can you change the toolbar type to 'No toolbar' and save the properties and then check ? Looks like a known issue

Comment: That's not  way. What does behavior of Show Toolbar ?

Comment: I presume you want the New Item Button, View Selector and search box as displayed on a View page, Those are onl;y displayed on a View page not when the list is a WebPart on another page

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman It displays on web part page if toll bar type is set to "Summary toolbar" in publishing page.

Comment: I stand corrected